# Creating a discrete distribution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, distribution

I want to create my own discrete distribution in Visual Studio with 121 integers. Here is the code I am trying:

```
std::vector< int> weights(121);
for (int i = 0; i < 121; i++)
{
    weights[i] = (teamData[i]).S(); // some numbers from my program data 
}
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());
```

I get the intellisence error:

```
1   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::discrete_distribution<_Ty>::discrete_distribution [with _Ty=int]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>)
```

and when I compile I get:

Error   1   error C2661: 'std::discrete_distribution::discrete_distribution' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
Does anyone know to fix this?

Comment: That's an intellisense error, does it actually compile? Isn't intellisense just the auto-complete in VS?

Comment: I just added the error I get when I compile

Comment: Looks like it is getting caught up when you declare dist. The default type for discrete_distribution is <int> but you are trying to initialize it with iterators to an int vector. I think that would only work if you were passing it a set of integers instead of two arguments that don't represent integers.

Comment: @RyanP Thanks, but I am not sure how to pass a set of integers into the distribution.

Comment: If you google my error message, there is one link and it just says to update VS 2013, and I did that, and still get same error.

Comment: try the code in my answer. i think you are missing an `int&` but i haven't used that function before and i don't have any test setup to compile it currently... but I think it'll work

Comment: @Pii hi, how did you solve your problem? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution

You are initializing it with iterators so you need to use this constructor

```
template< class InputIt >
discrete_distribution( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

So I'm guessing it should be `std::discrete_distribution<int&> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());`

But I haven't used discrete_distribution before.

Comment: It says that "dist" is undefined when I try to use it !

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the class template! you fixed my issue!

Comment: Awesome to hear! Make sure to mark this as your accepted answer, working on my reputation  :)

Comment: hi sorry, I am getting "unresolved external error" from template< class InputIt >. Where should I paste this code?

Comment: If it is a new issue, I'd make a new question. If it is directly related to this, I'd update your original question.

Comment: Thanks ok. I made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169695/creating-a-custom-interated-discrete-evolutionary-distribution